# It takes $n$ draws from an urn to draw the first red ball, what is the proportion of red balls in the urn?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

An urn contains many balls of various colours. I sample without replacement, and I stop sampling whenever I draw the first Red ball. If it takes $n$ draws from an urn to draw the first Red ball, what is the proportion of Red balls in the urn?

Presumably, this fact gives some Probability Distribution Function over the proportion of Red balls in the urn. How do I figure out this PDF?

---

A commenter points out that it depends on my prior, as the update is done as follows (where $evidence$ is my observing a Red ball after $n$ draws:

$$P(proportion|evidence)=\frac{P(evidence|proportion)P(proportion)}{P(evidence)}$$

where $P(proportion)$ is my prior for the proportion of Red balls (of all balls in the urn). Suppose my prior is uniform on the $[0,0.01]$ interval. How do I calculate the PDF of the posterior proportion given my evidence?

Comment: This could be a standard exercise in Bayesian reasoning, but you need a prior distribution.  For instance, if the only prior possibilities are that exactly five balls are red, or none of the balls are red, then the conclusion is that it's certain there were exactly five red balls.  On the other hand, if every number of red balls is equally likely, then there would be a probability distribution (which would depend on $n$ and on the number of balls originally in the urn).  What's your prior?

Comment: It would help, additionally, if you could tell us if you encountered this problem in a textbook, in the wild, or if you just made it up.

Comment: @BrianTung Suppose I'm not sure what prior to adopt. Suppose I have a uniform prior over the total number of balls in the urn from $1$ to $K$, how does one get the PDF from this fact?

Comment: When you sample without replacement, you can't just talk about proportions; things depend on the actual numbers of balls (red and total). If you replace "without replacement" by "with replacement", all that matters is the proportion of red balls. But a uniform prior can at most be an approximation, since with probability $1$ it results in an irrational proportion that can't actually be realized.